# Automating approved screen scraping with a twist

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, watin

I have approval to scrape some data from a third party website.  The scraping works great, however now there is a road block due to the new login process.  The new login process is a mixture of smartcard, java and jQuery.  My plan now is to use something like WatiN to accomplish the end goal.  What the program needs to do...

Open IE to allow the user to navigate to the certificate logon.  The user will login using their certificate.

The application will navigate to a post login page and begin the scraping.  With WatiN, I am able to log in and open the post login page, however I am not able to do much after that.

What I need to figure out is a way to take my console application, open IE and log in (manually), and then let the scraper take over the IE window either visually or in the code.  Ideally I would like to take the cookies and HTML from the post login page in WatiN and begin my scrapping, I need to store the cookies due to page changes in the scraper.  Everytime I try to store the cookies, I get an error "Timeout waiting for the document to become avaliable"  Any ideas?

```
Browser browser = new IE();
        browser.GoTo(url);

        browser.WaitForComplete(); //does not seem to work
        string _html = browser.Html;
        var cook= browser.Eval("document.cookie");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across your question. Late I know, but it may help someone else.
I use the following to attach to an open Firefox session.
I use Firefox as it is not being used for browsing by the user and is less likely to have its settings changed.

```
Sub AttachToOrOpenNewBrowser(ByRef ff As WatiN.Core.Browser)
    Try
        'If Browser is open then attach to browser
        ff = Browser.AttachTo(Of FireFox)(Find.First)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Else open new Browser and attach to this NEW browser
        ff = New FireFox(Trim(url))
    End Try
End Sub
```

I call this sub from my code. before calling it I check that ff "is nothing" in case it is already attached as follows:

```
Sub MainWork()
   Dim ff As WatiN.Core.Browser
   If ff Is Nothing Then AttachToOrOpenNewBrowser(ff)
   'Do your scrape
End Sub
```